# Is there a way to declare two return values in one function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, return-value

```
Code 1:
total = 0
tot = 0

for i in range(0, 101):
    if i % 2:
        total += i
    elif i % 5:
        tot += i
print(total)
print(tot)

output:
2500
2000
```

```
Code 2:
total = 0
tot = 0
def function():
    for i in range(0, 101):
        if i % 2:
            total += i
        elif i % 5:
            tot += i
    return(total)
    return(tot)
a = function()
print(a)

output:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

I wanted to put the first code as a function (like I tried in code 2)

question 1: Is there a way to use two return values in one function?

question 2: If not, is there another way to make code 2 work?

Thank you for your time!

(Sorry if my pattern of asking a question is inappropriate, as I'm trying to get familiar with Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by `return total, tot`. Here's an example:

```py
total = 0
tot = 0

def function():
    global total
    global tot
    for i in range(0, 101):
        if i % 2:
            total += i
        elif i % 5:
            tot += i
    return total, tot

a = function()
print(a)
```

which will gives you `(2500, 2000)`.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm sorry, could you please explain it in detail. I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: First of all, you should define `total` and `tot` as a local variable inside your `function` to be returned.

Comment: If you want to make both variables as a global, than you should add `global total` and `global tot` before the for looping.

Comment: Thank you so much!